# В Rails JavaScript выполняется дважды

Tags: ajax, javascript, ruby-on-rails

Добрый день. Возникла проблема с ajax запросами. Они выполняются по два раза.

Форма:

```
= search_form_for @q, :url => users_search_path, remote: true, :method => :post do |f|
  = f.text_field :login_cont, :placeholder => t('helpers.placeholder.users_search')
  = f.submit t('helpers.submit.search'), :class => 'button', data: { disable_with: t('helpers.submit.processing') }
```

Js:

```
var data = <%= {
  :tpl => render(:file => 'users/search.html.haml')
}.to_json.html_safe %>;

$('#search_div').html(data.tpl);
```

Контроллер:

```
def search
    @q = User.search(params[:q])
    @result = @q.result(distinct: true)

      respond_to do |format|
        unless params[:q].blank?
          format.html
          format.js
        else
          format.html { render nothing: true }
          format.js { render nothing: true }
        end
      end

  end
```

Логи:

```
Started POST "/users/search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-12 16:47:07 +1000
Processing by UsersController#search as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"login_cont"=>"a"}, "commit"=>"Найти"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.7ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "users"."id") FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."login" ILIKE '%a%')
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."login" ILIKE '%a%')
  Rendered users/search.html.haml (4.7ms)
  Rendered users/search.js.erb (6.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 8.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)

Started POST "/users/search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-12 16:47:07 +1000
Processing by UsersController#search as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"login_cont"=>"a"}, "commit"=>"Найти"}
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.9ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "users"."id") FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."login" ILIKE '%a%')
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."login" ILIKE '%a%')
  Rendered users/search.html.haml (5.8ms)
  Rendered users/search.js.erb (7.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 9.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
```

Comment: Проблему решил.

Comment: В таком случае вам нужно или удалить вопрос, или, если считаете, что ваше решение может быть ценно для всего человечества - опубликуйте его, как ответ на собственный вопрос. Сделайте это, пожалуйста. Чтобы топик с вопросом не висел просто так.